# How to read form data using a RequestLogger inside of Testcafe and retrieve one of the form fields without the binary data from a file upload

Tags: node.js, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm trying to retrieve the HTTP Request Body Form Data inside of Testcafe using a RequestLogger. I am then trying to write the request body info to a file. The problem is, I only want the "operationName", not all the binary data from the file that gets uploaded in the request.

```
const logger = RequestLogger({ requestUrl, method: 'post' }, {
  logRequestBody: true,
  logResponseBody: true,
  stringifyRequestBody: true,
  stringifyResponseBody: true
});

fixture(`Career Pathways`)
  .page(`${baseUrl}`)
  .requestHooks(logger)

test('upload-resume', async t => {
  await t
    .click(Selector('button')
    //click on more stuff

  var file = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, `/request_logs/requests.json`));
  file.write("#7 Request Body: ": + logger.requests.request.body);
}
```

[image: HTTP Request Body Form Data:]

[image: Written To File]

I tried just creating a write stream and to write the request body data to a file. However, the file contains a bunch of binary data which I don't want. I just wanted to get the "operationName" only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write requests results in a file in a smarter way you need to use [`Custom Request Hook`](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402842/guides/intermediate-guides/intercept-http-requests#create-a-custom-request-hook)

```js
import { RequestHook } from 'testcafe';
import fs from 'fs/promises';

export class MyRequestHook extends RequestHook {
    constructor (requestFilterRules, responseEventConfigureOpts) {
        super(requestFilterRules, responseEventConfigureOpts);
        // ...
    }
    async onRequest (event) {
        // ...
    }
    async onResponse (event) {
        await fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, `/request_logs/requests.json`), event.body.opertaions.opertaionName);
    }
}
```